# Scala drivers for couchdb and partial schemas

Tags: scala, couchdb

One question I have about current Scala couchdb drivers is whether they can work with "partial" schemas". I'll try to explain what I mean: the libraries I've see seem to all want to do a complete conversion from JSON docs in the database to a Scala object, handle the Scala object, and convert it back to JSON. This is is fine if your application knows everything about that type of object --- especially if it is the sole piece of software interacting with that database. However, what if I want to write a little application that only knows about part of the JSON object: for example, what if I'm only interested in a 'mybook' component embedded like this:

```
{
  _id: "0ea56a7ec317138700743cdb740f555a",
  _rev: "2-3e15c3acfc3936abf10ea4f84a0aeced",
  type: "user",
  profiles: {
    mybook: {
      key: "AGW45HWH",
      secret: "g4juh43ui9hg929gk4"
    },
    .. 6 or 7 other profiles
  },
  .. lots of other stuff
}
```

I really don't want to convert the whole JSON AST to a Scala object. On the other hand, in couchdb, you must save back the entire JSON doc, so this needs to be preserved somehow. I think what I really what is something like this:

```
class MyBook {
  private val userJson: JObject = ... // full JSON retrieved from the database
  lazy val _id: String = ... // parsed from the JSON
  lazy val _rev: String = ... // parsed from the JSON
  lazy val key: String = ... // parsed from the JSON
  lazy val secret: String = ... // (ditto)
  def withSecret(secret: String): MyBook = ... // new object with altered userJson
  def save(db: CouchDB) = ... // save userJson back to couchdb
}
```

Advantages:

- computationally cheaper to extract only needed fields
- don't have to sync with database evolution except for 'mybook' part
- more suitable for development with partial schemas
- safer, because there is less change as inadvertently deleting fields if we didn't keep up with the database schema

Disadavantages:

- domain objects in Scala are not pristinely independent of couch/JSON
- more memory use per object

Is this possible with any of the current Scala drivers? With either of scouchdb or the new Sohva library, it seems not.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a good JSON library and a good HTTP client library, implementing a schemaless CouchDB client library is really easy.

Here is an example in Java: [code](https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabase.java), [tests](https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabaseTest.java).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm experimenting with writing a driver in Scala at the moment. Fairly straightforward, but also quite lot of fiddle to cover the entire API.

Comment: @SamStainsby: Is your driver available somewhere?

Comment: @KimStebel Very soon it will be.

Comment: @Aurelien: I don't think reinventing the wheel is a good idea when all he needs is his own JSON parsers.

Comment: @Kim Reinventing the wheel may be not a good idea, but if you have the choice between getting a whole truck (containing wheels) and "building" a wheel from a tire and a rim, I prefer the second option.
For example, people wouldn't tell Java is slow and memory greedy if developers were more wary about the libraries they include...

Comment: @KimStebel Personally, I would never downvote an opinion just because I have a different one to promote.
If your answer is a better approach, I will be glad to see it get more votes, but please, don't tell me it is a "dangerously wrong" opinion to say what every REST book corroborates.

Comment: @KimSteibel And how could you blame someone for not knowing on Nov 3 a library you published on GitHub on Dec 6?

Comment: I don't blame them for not knowing my library, I think what I showed in my answer would be possible with other libraries as well, although maybe not as easily. It's not even a feature of my library but of spray-json. I never said your answer is "dangerously wrong". It's just wrong. ;) Of course that is my opinion, but what else would I express with downvotes, if not my negative opinion of other people's answers? Feel free to downvote my answer, if you think your approach is better.

Comment: My answer was indeed about finding good libraries for HTTP and JSON . So if spray-json is the library to go for JSON, I'm quite pleased with that. My examples were *only examples* to show that with any language, it should be easy to combine both libraries to get a CouchDB library.

On the 'meta' side, "dangerously wrong" was NOT a reference to what you said but to StackOverflow user manual: 

"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: My CouchDB driver is somewhat delayed after I decided to switch to using Scala 2.10 futures and Netty directly, rather than driver -> Dispatch -> Async HTTP -> Netty .. everyone needs a hobby over the Christmas break :-) .. Implementation is done, but some test are still failing. Will GitHub it once the tests pass.

Comment: It's up, altohugh no release cut as yet: https://github.com/stainsby/uniscala-couch .. will make 0.1 release over the weekend most likely.

Answer (score 0):

[My couchDB library](https://github.com/KimStebel/sprouch) uses spray-json for (de)serialization, which is very flexible and would enable you to ignore parts of a document but still save it. Let's look at a simplified example:

Say we have a document like this

```
{
  dontcare: {
      ...
  },
  important: "foo"
}
```

Then you could declare a class to hold information from this document and define how the conversion is done:

```
case class Dummy(js:JsValue)
case class PartialDoc(dontcare: Dummy, important: String)
implicit object DummyFormat extends JsonFormat[Dummy] {
  override def read(js:JsValue):Dummy = Dummy(js)
  override def write(d:Dummy):JsValue = d.js
}
implicit val productFormat = jsonFormat2(PartialDoc)
```

This will ignore anything in `dontcare` but still safe it as a raw JSON AST. Of course this example is not as complex as the one in your question, but it should give you an idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: I wrote this https://github.com/stainsby/uniscala-json to cater for my needs. My couch driver is also about to go up on GitHub. Diversity :-)

Comment: Some call it diversity, some call it reinventing the wheel. :-)

Comment: People reinvent wheels all the time - for good reasons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_track